# How to show my iCloud Calendar entries in my Android calendar app?

Tags: icloud, calendar, android

I know this may sound stupid, but I can't figure out how to sync my Android calendar app with my iCloud Calendar?

All I want to do is to display my business appointments (MacBook Pro; Owner) on my private phone (Honor ??; Subscriber). I don't even need to update them from my phone.

I tried to share it (Apple -> Android), but it wants me to create an Apple ID. I have a private one already, but I don't see any possibility to add it to my Android calendar apps. Neither default calendar app nor Google Calendar.

And accessing the calendar over the web browser is utterly pathetic (Ignoring the fact that Apple prevents access from "non-apple devices" anyway - in 2019).

Comment: Does your last paragraph answer your question?

Comment: See : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/218793/237687

Comment: @SolarMike well, I couldn't believe this is for real... Thanks, will check your link.